# vba - Find breaks if not found in external file

Tags: vba, excel

A little bit simplified but essentially what I want is to find multiple fields in an external file (without opening it) and have a Default value if not found.

I first have to search for a string prefix, which works, but then I have to adopt to existing or non-existing endings

Something like this:

```
Set src = Workbooks.Open(CStr(FilePath & Filename), True, True)
Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
For Each Roww In Range("A3:A14").Rows
        With src.Worksheets(srcSheet)
            cellSearch = "*" & wb.Range("A" & Roww.Row) & "*)"
            cellSearch = Replace(cellSearch , " -C-", "")

            'this works
            cellVal = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cellSearch , After:=.Range("A1"))

            'this breaks if not found
            findPlaceHolder = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cellVal & ", UK", After:=.Range("A1"))

            If findPlaceHolder = "" Then
                wb.Range("E" & rowHelp) = 0
            Else
                wb.Range("E" & rowHelp) = findPlaceHolder
            End If
```

Of course, it could very well be the case, that the first find only works because it is always successful and finds all fields.

Comment: is your question regarding the `this breaks if not found` comment? If not, what is your question because I don't see a real question in the post as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look up Find as there is plenty of documentation available. You should also get in the habit of declaring your variables and using Option Explicit. You need to check if anything is found first

```
Sub x()

Dim cellVal As Range, findPlaceHolder As Range

Set src = Workbooks.Open(CStr(FilePath & Filename), True, True)
Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
For Each roww In Range("A3:A14").Rows
        With src.Worksheets(srcSheet)
            cellSearch = "*" & wb.Range("A" & roww.Row) & "*)"
            cellSearch = Replace(cellSearch, " -C-", "")

            Set cellVal = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cellSearch, After:=.Range("A1"))
            If Not cellVal Is Nothing Then
                Set findPlaceHolder = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cellVal & ", UK", After:=.Range("A1"))
                If findPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then
                    wb.Range("E" & rowHelp) = 0
                Else
                    wb.Range("E" & rowHelp) = findPlaceHolder
                End If
            End If
        End With
Next roww

End Sub
```